# Transfer ether from account A to contract and then contract to account B

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am trying to write a code that:

1. Send 10000000000000000 wei (0.01 ether) from metamask accountA to a smart contract
2. Send ether from smart contract to accountB

I have written the code bellow and deployed via metamask. The amount 0.01 goes in the smart contract and I can check the balance is correct.

```
contract ONE {

    address payable public  owner;

    constructor()  payable   {
        owner=payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive () external payable {}

function sendViaCall(address payable _to ) payable external  {

        (bool sent, ) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
        
    }

function GetBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

However when I try to send ether from the contract to an accountB, this is not working.

I write the address on the box bellow and call the function on metamask, but it is not sending ether to Account B.

[image]

what I am doing wrong ?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running and not throwing error because `msg.value` is 0. every time you call `sendViaCall`, you are sending a 0 amount.

If you want to send `msg.value` alongside the function call on Remix, Remix does not have this functionality (Or maybe I could not figure out). In front end setup, when we call a contract function, we pass the last argument to the function `{value:amountToSend}` and this was received as `msg.value` inside the contract function.

If you want to test sending balance, you could use `address(this).balance`

```
function sendViaCall(address payable _to ) external payable  {
    (bool sent, ) = _to.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```